# Difference between return from Python 2 --version check and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, python-2.x

Why does the return from running the `--version` check on Python 2 behave differently than that on Python 3? Below is an example of the two behaviors when writing their output to a text file and subsequently checking the contents of that file.

```
C:\Users\user1>C:\Python27\python.exe --version >> file2.txt
Python 2.7.13

C:\Users\user1>type file2.txt

C:\Users\user1>C:\Python38\python.exe --version >> file3.txt

C:\Users\user1>type file3.txt
Python 3.8.1

C:\Users\user1>
```

Is there any way to produce the same behavior as Python 3? I would like to use the output from the `--version` check command as part of a batch file to ensure the proper version is being used to execute a script.

Comment: Create two aliases for them

Comment: Interesting, Python 2 outputs on stderr…? Redirecting stderr would help then, but I'm not familiar with Windows here…

Comment: Maybe your verification will be easier directly in python; for instance using `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info)'; if sys.version_info.major < 3: (do something) `

Comment: Do `C:\Python27\python.exe --version 2> file2.txt` to redirect _STDERR_ to the file. The `>>` should be changed to `>` (which is equivalent to `1>` to redirect _STDOUT_), unless you really want to *append* to the file. To write both _STDOUT_ and _STDERR_ to the file, use `… > "file.txt" 2>&1`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2 seems to output the version information to *STDERR* (handle `2`) rather than *STDOUT* (handle `1`), so change:

```cmd
C:\Python27\python.exe --version >> file2.txt
```

to:

```cmd
C:\Python27\python.exe --version 2> file2.txt
```

The [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) operator `>>` is used to *append* to a file; to (over-)write, use `>` instead.

To write both *STDOUT* and *STDERR* to the file, use this (replace `??` by `27` or `34`):

```cmd
C:\Python??\python.exe --version > "file.txt" 2>&1
```

The expression `2>&1` means to redirect handle `2` to the current target of handle `1`, which is the given text file due to `> "file.txt"`. Note that `>` is equivalent to `1>`, since the default handle for output redirection is `1` (*STDOUT*). The order is important here (so `2>&1 > "file.txt"` would fail).

This works also when appending to a file:

```cmd
C:\Python??\python.exe --version >> "file.txt" 2>&1
```

---

To get the result directly into a variable without a (temporary) file, use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) – in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %V in ('C:\Python??\python.exe --version 2^>^&1') do set VAR=%V
```

and in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%V in ('C:\Python??\python.exe --version 2^>^&1') do set VAR=%%V
```

Note the [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) using `^` that is necessary to avoid the redirection to be attempted too early.

To store only the pure version number into the variable without the word `Python` in front, replace `delims=` by `tokens=2`.

---

Let us even go a step further: You could let a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) search all available Python versions on its own. Given that the directory paths containing `python.exe` are listed in the [system variable `PATH`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), you could use [`where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) to get the full paths to the executables, then let `for /F` loop through them to get their exact versions (the version number is simply echoed out here just for demonstration):

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%W in ('where python') do (
    for /F "tokens=2" %%V in ('"%%W" --version 2^>^&1') do (
        echo %%V
    )
)
```

If the `PATH` variable does not contain the paths, you could alternatively search all paths `C:\Python??` using [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) (here `??` is meant literally as [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)); `where` just checks whether there is actually a file `python.exe`:

```cmd
@echo off
for /D %%X in ("%SystemDrive%\Python??") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%W in ('where "%%~X":python 2^> nul') do (
        for /F "tokens=2" %%V in ('"%%W" --version 2^>^&1') do (
            echo %%V
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this method to send the stderr and stdout to a file and then set the 1st line of the file to a variable using `set /p var=<file.txt`.

Comment: There is actually no need for a (temporary) file to put the result in a variable – see my edit…

Comment: Even better! I was trying to do so before, but I got hung up on the syntax to write both to a variable. Looking at your answer I can see I was making it more complicated than needed.  I like the idea to check all available python versions, but for my use case the user needs to provide the path to the executable.

Answer (score 2):

The Python 2 behavior was to send `--version` to stderr.  This was changed to stdout in Python 3.4, but not backported, out of concern for being a breaking change:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue18338
- https://bugs.python.org/issue28160
- https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.4.html#changes-in-python-command-behavior

You can [redirect stderr](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) to ensure the same behavior, e.g. that Python MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH is written to file.